# Gitlab fork project

Tags: gitlab

Would anyone know, if a parent project is deleted. Would it have an impact on the forked project on gitlab? except for the fact that the relationship is broken. Would the fork continue to act as an independent repo/project?

Answer (score 0):

Three questions:

1. Would anyone know, if a parent project is deleted?

   - Only if you try push or pull from/to the origin project (afaik)
2. Would it have an impact on the forked project on gitlab

   - Your forked project is a copy and will not be affected if the original project will be deleted
3. Would the fork continue to act as an independent repo/project?

   - Same as above

You could also try some scenarios yourself. You could use https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/ as a starting point

Comment: Thank you @stacker